# How to set the content type with Grails mail plugin?

Tags: java, email, grails, content-type, grails-plugin

The [Grails mail plugin documentation](http://app.name=mangelbaum_dev) shows only how to set the content type with GSP templates:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
```

But I don't use GSP (and will not!) and produce a String with FreeMarker. Is there a way to set the content type without using GSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the html statement in the sendMail method the plugin will set the content type for you.  The sendMail command can be used without requiring a gsp template.

```
mailService.sendMail {
            to "recipient@recipient.com"
            from "someone@place.com"
            subject "Email without gsp"
            html "some markup"
        }
```